# Duda con obtener información de forma dinámica mediante AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, setinterval

Tengo un mapa hecho con OpenLayers, y necesito cada x tiempo recibir información actualizada en forma de Geojson, para poder posicionar diferentes elementos en tiempo real sobre el mapa. Estoy utilizando setInterval para recoger esas respuestas que hago con el objeto XMLHttpRequest y mi viendo la ejecución. Lo hace bien, si modifico el geojson, se muestra el cambio, pero, ¿es una mala práctica?. ¿Hay otra forma de recoger información en tiempo real?.

Este es mi código:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var requestURL = "data.geojson";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            console.clear();
            console.log(request.response);
        }
    }
    var prueba = setInterval(function () {
        request.open('GET', requestURL, true);
        request.send();
    }, 6000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, es una buena práctica. Hay otras formas como los WebWorker, te dejo el enlace: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp .
Si quieres recoger información en tiempo real debes utilizar WebSocket, pero es más complicado ya que debes tener un lenguaje en el backend con soporte para WebSocket (Java o NodeJS por ejemplo). WebSocket es genial para tu proposito de tiempo real, websocket establece una conexión bidireccional cliente/servidor y permite al servidor enviar información al cliente sin necesidad de que exista una petición previa por parte del cliente. te dejo un enlace: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket . Otra opción es SSE (Server Sent Event), aunque también es algo más compleja y no es tiempo real. SSE permnite al servidor enviar información al cliente sin petición previa al igual que WebSocket, pero no existe una conexión bidireccional en la que el cliente pueda enviar información al servidor. Te dejo un enlace: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp . Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por la aportación! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Siempre puedes sustituir `setInterval` por un `setTimeout` recursivo, ya que `setInterval` puede dar ciertos errores a veces (la función, si no necesita parámetros de entrada, mejor definirla fuera).

El cambio se vería tal que así:

```
setTimeout(actualiza, 6000);
function actualiza () {
            request.open('GET', requestURL, true);
            request.send();
            setTimeOut(actualiza,6000);
        }
```

Además de esta forma te aseguras que no se empiecen a solapar las llamadas al servicio, ya que el `setInterval` comienza a contar el tiempo para la siguiente llamada desde que ejecuta el código, `setTimeout` lo ejecuta una vez, al acabar la llamada vuelves a definir otro exactamente igual por lo que se ejecutará siempre 6 segundos (en este caso) tras la actualización anterior.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, lo probaré.